# How to translate a sprite and a vertex geometry by the same distance?

Tags: c#, .net, xna, 3d

I'm trying to build up a 2.5 engine with XNA. Basically, I want to display a 2D sprites (the main hero and other monsters) in a 3D background. The game will be a platform.
Now, using a translation matrix on a sprite doesn't yield the same result of translate a vertex geometry in world space.
I mean, if I apply

```
Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(viewportWidth / 2, viewportHeight / 2, 0));
```

the sprite will be translate at the middle of screen (starting from the display upper left origin). But, if I apply the same transform to a cube in world space, it will translate very far. This doesn't suprising me, but I wonder of to translate a sprite and a 3D object by the same distance, ignoring all the project/unproject coord stuffs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are traditionally three matrices: World, View and Project.

`BasicEffect`, and most other 3D Effects, simply have those matrices. You use Project to define how points are projected  from the 3D world onto the 2D viewport ((-1,-1) in the bottom-left of the viewport to (1,1) in the top-right). You set View to move your camera around in world space. And you use World to move your models around in world space.

`SpriteBatch` is a bit different. It has an implicit Project matrix that causes your world space to match the viewport's client space ((0,0) in the top-left and (width,height) in the bottom-right). You can pass a `transformMatrix` matrix to `Begin` which you can generally think of like the View matrix. And then the parameters you pass to `Draw` (position, rotation, scale, etc) work like the World matrix would.

If you need to do "weird" things to your World or Project matrices in `SpriteBatch`, you can just build those transforms into your `transformMatrix`. It may just involve some maths to "undo" the built-in transformations.

In XNA 4 you can also use an `Effect` (like `BasicEffect`) directly in `SpriteBatch`, which you can provide with arbitrary matrices ([details](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/05/spritebatch-and-custom-shaders-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx)).